# How to convert invalid string format date values to null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have string column and I want to convert the field into a date.

I'm trying the following query but getting an error :

```
select cast('20160532' as date) AS dt;
```

When I am selecting the output is null because 32 is not a date, but when I am inserting this record to a table it gives an error:

> "incorrect date value 20160532"

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-str_to_date/) - it will return `NULL` when the string is not in a correct date format :

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20160532', '%Y,%m,%d')
```

Comment: it returns null even if date is valid, eg `20150528`

Comment: use : ** SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20150532', '%Y%m,%d')**

Comment: Getting same error message (incorrect datetime value 20160532) while INSERTING the record to a table

Comment: so you are telling me this `20150525` should also return NULL? even though it is a valid date

Comment: the record 20150525 is  valid and insert without any problem but 20160532 in not a valid date 32. that's why the record is not inserting. i want to insert null against these type of invalid values

Comment: use **insert into YOURTABLE (date_field_name) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('20160532', '%Y%m%d'));**

Comment: unable to insert the record

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd8338/1

```
INSERT INTO t (my_date) VALUES
(IF((@d :=  STR_TO_DATE('20160532', '%Y%m%d')) IS NULL, null, @d));

INSERT INTO t (my_date) VALUES
(IF((@d :=  STR_TO_DATE('20160525', '%Y%m%d')) IS NULL, null, @d));
```

Comment: insert into  dt(dt) 
select coalesce(date('20160532'),'1900-01-01'); unable to insert record. can some one help me out.